# How to rotate a view once the user has re-entered?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

Bellow I have some code that i have placed in my **AppDelegate.h & .m**. This code detects when my MPMoviePlayerController(s) have entering full-screen and exited full-screen through notifications. Once the notifications are called it sets `allowRotation` to equal yes and this then allows the user to rotate the view. However once the user has excited full-screen and is still in a certain oreinentation the player dismisses but leaves view in the orieintation that it was place in by the user whilst watching the video. This is due to the exit-full-screen notification being called but the `-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window` not being called. So it only re-rotates to port rate when the user rotates the device. But I do not want this and want it to rotate as soon as the notification is called. can anybody help?

**Here is my code:**

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL allowRotation;


@end
```

**.m**
   @synthesize  allowRotation;

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    allowRotation = NO;
    return YES;
}

- (void) MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"calling1");
    self.allowRotation = NO;
}


- (void) moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"calling");
    self.allowRotation = YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (self.allowRotation == YES) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
    else if (self.allowRotation == NO){
        NSLog(@"portrait");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface rotation calls are called when the UI layout is done at the start and changing that dynamically at a later point is not going to change the orientation.

Comment: you can manually rotate using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. Take a look at the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390359/how-to-rotate-a-view-in-controller-that-is-not-allowed-to-rotate-its-interface?rq=1